# Assing ng-false-value by default to model

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to set the value in ng-false-value to the checkboxes if the ng-true-value evaluates to false.

```
<span data-ng-repeat="val in value track by val.levelId">
  <input type="checkbox" data-ng-model="val.levelId" data-ng-true-value="{{isINFemale(val.levelId,key)}}" data-ng-false-value="-1"/>
</span>
```

Comment: Do you need this? data-ng-model="isINFemale(val.levelId,key)}}"

Comment: yes I need some mechanism through which i can run ng true and ng false as if else code.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing out the ng-checked attribute. Try this...

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="myCtrl">
    My value <input type="checkbox" ng-true-value="{{box.true}}" ng-false-value="{{box.false}}" ng-model="myValue" ng-checked="myValue == box.true">
    {{myValue}}
</div>

function myCtrl($scope){
    $scope.box = {true: 1, false: -1}
    $scope.myValue = $scope.box.true;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L04jmxr8/)

--EDIT--

In your case add the following.

```
<span data-ng-repeat="val in value track by val.levelId">
  <input type="checkbox" data-ng-model="val.levelId" data-ng-true-value="{{isINFemale(val.levelId,key)}}" data-ng-false-value="-1" data-ng-checked="val.levelId == isINFemale(val.levelId,key)"/>
</span>
```

Comment: the work done by ng-checked is already being done by ng-true and ng-false . What I want is some mechanism through which i can set -1 to model value whenever ng-true expresion evaluates to false.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ternary operator in ng-true-value attribute.

```
<span data-ng-repeat="val in value track by val.levelId">
    <input type="checkbox" data-ng-model="val.levelId"
           data-ng-true-value="{{isINFemale(val.levelId,key) ? isINFemale(val.levelId,key) : (-1)}}" 
           data-ng-false-value="-1"/>
</span>
```

Hope this helps.